# duplicate a comment as an answer even when it is already answered with an answer?

Tags: discussion

if there's a question and somebody comments with an answer

somebody then posts an answer within the same minute, so clearly hasn't copied, but posts his answer.

Should I tell the commenter to make his comment an answer and i'll accept it?

If I do, then it's duplication

[Why is this nested LinearLayout not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24999640/why-is-this-nested-linearlayout-not-working)

GT posted his comment at 16:24:06

Agami posted his answer at 16:24:42

They are each equally good.. neither has additional information.

One didn't copy off the other.

GT did beat him to the answer, though as a comment.

Comment: Yes, but Akagami posted an *answer,* FTW

Comment: Sometimes you'll find low hanging fruits, and you should just catch them. There's nothing really wrong with it. Though some questions, aren't worth being answered, because of just being trivial. You still have to triage, if the question is worth answering at all, or we should send it to the close vote limbo.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it's picking  not catching. If they're low hanging, then they're hanging, they're stationary, and you'd pick them as they are easily reached, rather than catching them.

Answer (score 2):

Comments don't count as answers; if GT wanted credit for answering the question, e should have posted an answer. Putting a solution in a comment is, strictly speaking, an improper use of the comment system. They're usually too short to hold all the required information; they can't be edited by anyone after five minutes; they can't be downvoted or accepted.

You're welcome to ask GT to repost the comment, but if you're going to decide a run-off for your accepted answer based on time of posting, I'd say you should indeed go with Akagami's, since it is in fact an *answer*.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @Infinite, but the 'e' was intentional; G.T. is a person of unknown gender.