# Give credit/reputation to original author of solution

Tags: feature-request, reputation

You may have seen this situation a lot of times:

A guy answers the question in a comment, but comments are easy to become forgotten. Thus another guy takes the original author's solution and posts it as an answer, which is great for a lot of people, but it is originally not his solution.

Wouldn't it be cool, for the second guy to offer the credits to @OriginalPoster?

Example: [Glassfish DeploymentException: Error in linking security policy for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322476/glassfish-deploymentexception-error-in-linking-security-policy-for/18699520#18699520)

Comment: Downvotes on meta just mean people don't agree with your post, so don't take them personal. The answers you've received probably summarize the reason your question has been downvoted.

Comment: Thanks @NathanArthur, wasn't really clear about that.

Comment: Converting comment into an answer is expected behavior - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269913/comment-poaching, also depending on amount of effort marking "community wiki" may be preferable to taking ownership (see search results for more discussions https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=answer+in+comments). Note that often exactly the same solution can be independently posted as comment and answer at the same time - claiming that one took idea from another may not always have base in reality.

Comment: Sometimes Joe post a comment instead of a answer, Because Joe don't have time to check if it really works,  or just gave a pro tips and have no time for more, because Joe try to write an answer but it doesnt match Joe's standard so it get rejected by his innerself. Sometimes Joe write a comment  to claim first but get shoot by a the FGITW while writting his complete answer.

Comment: Most of the time if I answer questions in the comments I do so with simple code, the reason I don't post them as answers because I can't be bothered to write out a full explanation of why that would work or what they were doing wrong, if someone else does answer with the code and an explanation, why shouldn't they get the rep :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a comment isn't answering. 
Notice that comment has max length and answer havs minimum length and that because they have different purpose.

When you comment you don't take any risk (mainly of down voting). The person who answer takes risk and should check and append to the solution described in the comment.

Comment: I also use comments for things like "Hmm, try doing X and Y" because I don't have enough information to actually *answer* the question, but those steps can generate enough that I *could.* It isn't even because the question is incomplete or unclear, but rather a problem with multiple causes and what the Asker needed was someone with more experience debugging the problem. If X *does* work, then its easy to expand and explain *why* X worked. Doesn't matter to me if I do it or someone else does (ditto if I see a comment someone else made that worked: I'll generally give them a day or two to do it)

Answer (score 15):

If they wanted the reputation (or honestly, even if they didn't) they shouldn't have posted an answer in the comments; they should have posted an answer.

Answer (score 7):

No, "answers" in comments do not need reputation as it is explicit (also probably misguided) choice by author to not create real answer. The very common reason to post answer in comments is to explicitly avoid reputation loss on partial/unrelated answer for unclear questions.

If actual answer is 100% copied from the comment it should be marked community wiki and mention author of the original source. If answer just happen to have the same idea (whether inspired by the comment or independently arrived to the same solution) there is no additional requirements to cite the comment.

See also [Comment Poaching](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269913/comment-poaching)